# When is $||Px||\leq||x||$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given that $P$ is a matrix with entries belonging to $\mathbb{C}^n$, when can we say that $\Vert Px \Vert   \leq \Vert x \Vert \;\; \forall\;\; x \in \mathbb{C}^n $ ?

Based on the text I'm reading (which is related to dynamical systems), I understand the claim is that this happens when the absolute values of the eigenvalues of $P$ are lesser than or equal to 1. How do I show this?

Something what I did is to use the singular value decomposition and the properties of unitary matrices and arrive at the following :
$$ ||Px|| = ||UDV^*x||=||DV^*x||
 $$
Let $x=Vy$. This doesn't cause problems as $V$ is invertible (unitary)
$$ ||DV^*x||=||DV^*Vy||=||Dy|| 
$$
From this we get,
$$ ||Dy|| \leq ||y||$$
From this the condition is that the entries of $D$ must have their absolute values lesser than or equal to 1. However, I don't know how the entries of $D$ (which are the singular values of $P$) can be correlated with the eigenvalues of $P$.

Comment: What about $P = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 0 &0 \end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: @nicomezi $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 0 &0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ a\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2a \\ 0\end{bmatrix} $$
then $\| Px \| = 2|a|$ and $\|x\| =|a|$, doesn't work

Comment: Yes, you are right. And the only eigenvalue is $0$. So the statement he made about the eigenvalues is not correct as writen. @Physor

Comment: Yes, @nicomezi your counterexample is indeed correct. Is there a situation when the eigenvalues indeed decide the condition of the question? The text I'm reading proves it for a case when there exists an eigenbasis. If it may help, the matrix $P$ is the Jacobian from a previous computation. Maybe there's some subtlety in the theory which I may be missing as the original context is in dynamical systems

Comment: @Mohit The eigenvalues will only decide the condition if $P$ is normal (i.e. $PP^* = P^*P$, where $P^*$ denotes the conjugate-transpose of $P$). However, if $\|Px\| \leq \|x\|$ holds for all $x$, then it follows that the eigenvalues of $P$ have absolute value smaller than $1$.

Comment: The proof that the eigenvalues of $P$ must be less than $1$ in absolute value can be done as follows. You want to show that $\|Px\|\leq \|x\|$ for all $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$, but now suppose towards contradiction that $P$ has an eigenvalue greater than $1$, then there is a unit vector $v$ (the normalized eigenvector with eigenvalue $|a|>1$) such that $\|Pv\|=\||a|v\|=|a|\|v\|>\|v\|$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Condo. Thanks. So I think the answer to this would be that the absolute values of eigenvalues being lesser than 1 is a necessary but not sufficient condition. It is a necessary and sufficient condition if an eigenbasis exists as shown in the answer by Yves below.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think the eigenvalues will decide the condition if an eigenbasis exists. Refer my previous comment.

Comment: A normal matrix is diagonalizable (in $\mathbb{C}$). However having an eigenbasis is not a necessary condition. Consider the same example as in my first comment but with $0.1$ instead of $2$.

Comment: @MohitKumar That only works if the eigenbasis is known in advance. Note that the matrix
$$
P(t) = \pmatrix{0&t\\0&1/2}
$$
has an eigenbasis for all $t > 0$, but as $t \to \infty$ so does $\|P(t)\|$.